# Qt for android - not get the input focus in dialog

Tags: android, qt

I have developed a QT application by QT widgets that can run on Windows and Android platforms.

The application has dialog boxes, which contain text boxes. When running on Android platform, the text boxes of the dialog boxes can not get the input focus. The input focus is always on the text box of the main window. How to solve this problem?

https://forum.qt.io/topic/100078/qt-for-android-input-focus/2

QT 5.10

Comment: Please, provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Thks for remind, It help me found out why. Because i have call setting  windowFlags funtion, setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::Tool), it causing problems to occur.